# converting money into all possible combinations

Tags: java

I know my question is repeated but I still couldn't understand what the other answers are explaining.  Below is my code and I have calculated it to get to the first line which is `57 pennies + 0 dimes + 0 nickels + 0 quarters` and I am thinking to run a loop that will list all the possible combinations of pennies, dimes, nickels, quarters. But, I don't know how.

```
public class Conversion{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int cents = 57;

  int quarter = 25;
  int dime = 10;
  int nickel = 5;
  int penny = 1;


  int totalPennies = cents / penny;
  cents %= penny;
  int totalNickels = cents / nickel;
  cents %= nickel;
  int totalDimes = cents / dime;
  cents %= dime;
  int totalQuarters = cents / quarter;
  cents %= quarter;


  System.out.print(totalPennies + " pennies + ");
  System.out.print(totalNickels + " nickels + ");
  System.out.print(totalDimes + " dimes + ");
  System.out.println(totalQuarters + " quarters");

 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your order of operations is backwards.

The *first* thing you do is count how many pennies you have.  Since pennies are literally valued at 1, you can have 57 pennies and make up $0.57 just fine.  That is obviously not what you want to accomplish.

What you want to do is count from your *highest* denomination and work your way backwards.  Here's a sample.

```
// This should be the first operation
int totalQuarters = cents / quarter;
cents %= quarter;
```

I leave reordering the rest as an exercise for the reader, but the output then becomes correct once successfully reordered.

```
2 pennies + 1 nickels + 0 dimes + 2 quarters
```

Comment: But how do I output all the possible combinations?

Comment: As I said before @sara99, the output you have is fine, but the order in which you calculate those values isn't.  Just changing the order in which you do those operations will be enough to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Makoto, I will fix that right now. So I don't have to run a loop for the other possible combinations?

Comment: No, you do not require a loop.  In this case that'd only make things *worse*.

Comment: I got exactly the same output but I needed other possible outcomes.

Comment: For example: 2 pennies + 1 nickels + 0 dimes + 2 quarters

Comment: and 1 quarter + 1 dime + 4 nickels + 3 pennies

Comment: there are much more outcomes I wanted to know those outcomes.

Comment: * 2 pennies instead of 3 pennies

Comment: 4 nickles = 2 dimes @sara99

Comment: That is true but I need the output of all different methods or all different types of possibilities and there could be many more possibilities. I am sorry if I am not explaining this clearly.

Comment: You're explaining it clearly, but I'm telling you that there's no other concise way to define that since counting combinations of monetary denominations means that you have a shift towards larger coins as opposed to smaller coins.  If you want to be sure you're on the right track with what you've got here and what I've answered, talk with your professor or whomever assigned you the task.  I'll be considering this question thus resolved and will disengage for now - I can't spend too long chatting..  If you have a different question about your code then you can ask a new question on the site.

Comment: Let's say I have 100 cents so I need the outcome to be all the possible combinations: Examples: `4 quarters + 0 dime + 0 nickel + 0 pennies`,
`3 quarters + 1 dime + 0 nickel + 15 pennies` , ` 2 quarters + 2 dimes + 2 nickels + 20 pennies` and more combinations like that. All of these equal to 100 cents.

Comment: I see.  I may have misunderstood your original question (even if I fixed a symptom of it).  I see you're looking for *all* possible combinations as opposed to fixing it to find *a* combination.  That...would be a bit more broad in scope and effort than I have time to answer today, but given that I've given you a good start on how to solve *an* approach, would you mind making more headway with this and getting somewhere with the full combinatorics before asking a new question?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Makoto: [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255012/java-converting-cents-to-all-possible-combinations-of-quarts-dimes-nickels)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:  It almost feels like the goalposts were moved on this one.  The question was similar and I don't deny that the OP hadn't really made much progress with their problem, but...if they don't think that a similar question answered their question they're within their right to ask a new one.  I suppose this is a bit of a rock and a hard place then, but one that leaves us looking like the "bad guys" in this scenario.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:  (Also the comments were less than helpful.  If anything they may have exacerbated the problem.)

Comment: I disagree -- It looks to be the exact same question. I don't see how it has changed in any way other than her reversing the order of operations as per your suggestion.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:  Yes - I'm not advocating that the other question be reopened at all - but what I'm saying is that we haven't really helped anything here.  The OP likely didn't do their part in getting further with their problem and we don't have a clean mechanism to help with that.  However it just leaves me with an uneasy feeling that we've kind of set them up for failure in this context.

Comment: Also you have to agree that this very same question has been asked [many, many times previously on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+all+coin+combinations+site:stackoverflow.com), and that the question is a duplicate of many. She states that she's seen some of these duplicates but shows none of the fruits of her efforts to apply what she's read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183469/discussion-between-makoto-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels).